# how to restart youtube app

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am playing video in my app using youtube.

```
public void videoButtonAction(View v)
        {
              Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoLink);
              uri = Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"  + uri.getQueryParameter("v"));
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
              startActivity(intent);
        }
```

The video starts and plays fine. However there are two following issues:

1. At the end of end of the video, youtube recommends related videos: is it possible to have it only show the desired video only without other related stuff (like comments, reviews, related/recommended videos)?
2. When the back button is pressed after watching video, the control goes back to the activity which launched the youtube application which is fine and desired. However, I want to see another video using the same button. YouTube player shows new video on a small window within the related/recommended videos. Is it possible that whenever I hit the play video button to launch the YouTube, my app checks if YouTube is already running and kill it and start new one?

Comment: adding intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true); fixed the small window issues.

Answer (score 0):

As youtube is not your own app, you can't control its behaviour.

I would suggest you to integrate YouTube Player in your own app to customize the things as per your requirements.And yes,it is very easy to do so.you can find the sample projects with documentation.

Kindly go through [YouTube Player API for Android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) for samples and documentation.